# combine javascript objects with inner array with same key (similar to foriegn key )

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, merge

```
           Obj1 = [
                {
                    'id':1,
                    'name':'apple'
                },
                {
                    'id':2,
                    'name':'mango'
                }
            ]

            Obj2 = [
                {
                    'parentId' : 1,
                    'time': [1,2,3]
                },
                {
                    'parentId' : 1,
                    'time': [4,5,6]
                },
                {
                    'parentId' : 1,
                    'time': [7,8,9]
                },
                {
                    'parentId' : 2,
                    'time': [11,12]
                }
            ]


            result = [
            {
                    'id':1,
                    'name':'apple',
                    'time': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
                },
                {
                    'id':2,
                    'name':'mango',
                    'time': [11,12]
                },
            ]
```

How to combine these two objects who have same key in common with 
NodeJs or Javascript and get the following resulting object.

without using Jquery or any other framework.

Note : NodeJs application

Comment: what have you tried? do you know how to use a hash table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#map()`, `Array#filter()` and `concat()`

**Explication**

`arr1.map(a1=>{...})` => Create a new array based on `arr1`

`arr2.filter(a2=>a2.prentId===a1.id)` => Keep all the items with the `parentId` equals to the current `id`

`.map(a2=>a2.time)` => only keep the `time` array

`let times` is an array of array of times : `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`

`[].concat.apply([], times)` => flatten the `times` nested array

```js
const arr1=[{id:1,name:"apple"},{id:2,name:"mango"}],arr2=[{parentId:1,time:[1,2,3]},{parentId:1,time:[4,5,6]},{parentId:1,time:[7,8,9]},{parentId:2,time:[11,12]}];

let result = arr1.map(a1=>{
  let times = arr2.filter(a2=>a2.parentId===a1.id).map(a2=>a2.time);
  a1.time = [].concat.apply([], times);
  return a1;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: while you write, **what** you use, you don't explain **why** you use the whole stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj1=[{'id':1,'name':'apple'},{'id':2,'name':'mango'}];
const obj2=[{'parentId':1,'time':[1,2,3]},{'parentId':1,'time':[4,5,6]},{'parentId':1,'time':[7,8,9]},{'parentId':2,'time':[11,12]}];

const res = obj1.map(el => Object.assign(el, {time: obj2.filter(i => el.id === i.parentId).map(({time}) => time).join(',').split(',')}))

console.log(res)
```